# Does the union of a set of sets not contain sets as elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am new to set theory and I saw this problem online.

$A=\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$

Find $A\cup A$

I think that the answer is$A=\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$

However the answer is $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$

Is there some rule im not aware about its confusing me a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [Union of two sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)#Union_of_two_sets): thus, $A \cup A = \{ x \mid x \in A \text { or } x \in A \}$. You are right: the elements of $A \cup A$ are the elemnts of $A$.

Comment: The answer you have found conflate $A \cup A$ with $\bigcup A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that $A \cup A = A$.

$\bigcup A$ is equal to $\{1,2,3,4\}$. See wikipedia [arbitrary unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)#Arbitrary_unions).

Comment: Yes I made the mistake of confusing arbitray unions with unions thank you for clearing that up.